# SQL Group and Pivot on pair of rows into one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot

I have sensor data in a SQL Server 2016 table that looks like the following:

| Created | RealValue | Tag | Units | PairIdentity | PairConfigLabel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:50.030 | 67.3519982 | temperature | °F | BC72251E-08C0-471A-93A3-C2422C7AB80C | Cutting |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:50.030 | 53.299999 | humidity | % | BC72251E-08C0-471A-93A3-C2422C7AB80C | Cutting |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:50.030 | 53.25 | humidity | % | 7D7F8DAC-5BCB-4077-961F-2A985BB6D8CE | Assembly |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:50.030 | 67.0279982 | temperature | °F | 7D7F8DAC-5BCB-4077-961F-2A985BB6D8CE | Assembly |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:50.013 | 36.849998 | humidity | % | 1A857346-35D2-45FA-80C8-D6523B310026 | Laminating |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:50.013 | 71.564 | temperature | °F | 1A857346-35D2-45FA-80C8-D6523B310026 | Laminating |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:49.997 | 42.700001 | humidity | % | E8FC1476-F082-4C79-889A-5716FCE0A5B8 | SLA Lab |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:49.997 | 72.482 | temperature | °F | E8FC1476-F082-4C79-889A-5716FCE0A5B8 | SLA Lab |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:49.980 | 41.049999 | humidity | % | D5C651A4-3A4C-429B-88CA-22CBFEDE875D | QC Lab |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:49.980 | 73.3459982 | temperature | °F | D5C651A4-3A4C-429B-88CA-22CBFEDE875D | QC Lab |

For every temperature record, there is **usually, but not always**, a corresponding humidity reading (there could be humidity row, but no corresponding temp or vice versa).  They are tied together with the `PairIdentity` column.  I want to produce a query that Groups the data on the PairIdentity and Pivot it into a single row for each grouping with new columns.  I'm not sure if I've worded that correctly but I'm trying to achieve a result similar to this:

| Created | Temp | TempUnit | Humidity | HumidityUnit | PairIdentity | PairConfigLabel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:50.030 | 67.3519982 | °F | 53.299999 | % | BC72251E-08C0-471A-93A3-C2422C7AB80C | Cutting |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:50.030 | 67.0279982 | °F | 53.25 | % | 7D7F8DAC-5BCB-4077-961F-2A985BB6D8CE | Assembly |
| 2021-11-12 12:00:50.013 | 71.564 | °F | 36.849998 | % | 1A857346-35D2-45FA-80C8-D6523B310026 | Laminating |

Any tips or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is PairIdentity unique for a same F-% lecture?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a standard `case` pivot:

```
select
    min(Created) as Created,
    min(case when tag = 'temperature' then RealValue end) as Temp,
    min(case when tag = 'temperature' then Units end) as TempUnit,
    min(case when tag = 'humidity' then RealValue end) as Humidity,
    min(case when tag = 'humidity' then Units end) as HumidityUnit,
    PairIdentity,
    min(PairConfigLabel) as PairConfigLabel
from T
group by PairIdentity
```

Comment: This is the best solution for this scenario

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand very well your data or structure, or what you want, please comment here and I'll glad to update or correct my answer.

Main idea is get "two tables", one for temp and another for humidity, and join them by (if are unique between meditions) your `PairIdentity`.
Then show specific data as required for the joined table.

You can play with "this join" and the real data to get more precision.

```
    SELECT 
        temp.Created,
        temp.temperature as Temp,
        temp.Units as TempUnit,
        hum.humidity as Humidity,
        hum.Units as HumidityUnit,
        temp.PairIdentity,
        temp.PairConfigLabel
        FROM
        (
        SELECT
        Created,
        RealValue as temperature,
        Units,
        PairIdentity,
        PairConfigLabel
        FROM yourTable
        WHERE Tag = 'temperature'
        ) as temp
        JOIN
        (
        SELECT 
        Created,
        RealValue as humidity,
        Units,
        PairIdentity,
        PairConfigLabel
        FROM yourTable
        WHERE Tag = 'humidity'
        ) as hum
        ON temp.PairIdentity = hum.PairIdentity
```

Comment: Thank you!  Syntax error around a missing parenthesis (after JOIN) and ambiguous column name for 'Created' but it works!  Not letting me edit to correct the syntax.

Comment: sorry Jason, I did on the fly. Let me fix it and thanks for the update

Comment: @JasonEades done, thanks again and sorry again for mistakes. If this helps you and answer you, please dont forget to upvote and/or mark it as answer. Or please tell me if I can help you more or edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your sample data it appears you just need an inner join between the two data sets:

```
with tmp as (
    select * 
    from t
    where tag='temperature'
), hum as (
    select * 
    from t
    where tag='humidity'
)
select
    t.Created Created, 
    t.RealValue Temp,
    t.Units TempUnit,
    h.RealValue HunidityUnit,
    t.PairIdentity,
    t.PairConfigLabel
from tmp t join hum h on t.PairIdentity=h.PairIdentity;
```

Comment: This is fine, but is not good practice use SELECT *

Comment: @Leandro I disagree. There's no downside to using `*` here.

Comment: In a self-contained CTE such as this that's not returning the final result-set it's absolutely fine!

Comment: @shawnt00 why? I understand you don't select them, but is not a performance delimiter? Just asking trying to learn

Comment: @Leandro The performance impact is generally when you return all columns to the client. These aren't being returned of course. Consider this: `select ... from (select * from T) Tderived` which is basically what you're doing every time you mention a table in the from clause anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!